# write() system call ignores file permissions

Tags: files, permissions

I made a very simple program in C which writes "Test string" into file named "file.txt":

```
root@3:~# cat test.c
#include "unistd.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "stdio.h"

main()
{
  FILE *fp;
  int fd;

  fp = fopen("file.txt", "w");
  fd = fileno(fp);
  write(fd, "Test string\n", strlen("Test string\n"));
}
root@3:~#
```

I created a file named "file.txt" before I execute the `test`:

```
root@3:~# ls -l file.txt 
-r-------- 1 root root 0 sept  21 22:28 file.txt
root@3:~#
```

As seen above, `file.txt` has only read permissions. However, if I execute the `test`, the "Test string" is written into "file.txt":

```
root@3:~# strace ./test
execve("./test", ["./test"], [/* 22 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x188d000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc03a44e000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=30251, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 30251, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fc03a446000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\300\357\1\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1599504, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3713112, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fc039ea6000
mprotect(0x7fc03a028000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fc03a227000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x181000) = 0x7fc03a227000
mmap(0x7fc03a22c000, 18520, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc03a22c000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc03a445000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc03a444000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc03a443000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fc03a444700) = 0
mprotect(0x7fc03a227000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fc03a450000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fc03a446000, 30251)           = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x188d000
brk(0x18ae000)                          = 0x18ae000
open("file.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
write(3, "Test string\n", 12)           = 12
exit_group(12)                          = ?
root@3:~# cat file.txt
Test string
root@3:~#
```

How can this happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are able to write to the file because you are the `root` user.  Consider the following:

```
> cat file.txt
> ls -al file.txt
-r--------  1 sdanna  staff  0 Sep 21 20:43 file.txt
> ./a.out
Segmentation fault: 11
> sudo ./a.out
> cat file.txt
Test string
```

Here ./a.out is your presented program.  As you can see, when I run the command as a normal user, I receive a segmentation fault as I try to operate on the null pointer returned by the failed fopen.

If I run the command as `root` it works fine.  The root user can always write to the file unless the file's extended attributes are changed to prevent modification. The [path_resolution(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html) man page on linux, sums up the situation nicely:

> On a traditional UNIX system, the superuser (root, user ID 0) is all-
> powerful, and bypasses all permissions restrictions when accessing
> files.
>
> On Linux, superuser privileges are divided into capabilities (see
> capabilities(7)).  Two capabilities are relevant for file permissions
> checks: CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE and CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH.  (A process has
> these capabilities if its fsuid is 0.)
>
> The CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE capability overrides all permission checking,
> but grants execute permission only when at least one of the file's
> three execute permission bits is set.
>
> The CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH capability grants read and search permission
> on directories, and read permission on ordinary files.

The root user on Linux has both of the required capabilities.